# check variable is empty before add into dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

below code from AOSP build/core/Makefile

If someone set INSTALLED_RAMDISK_TARGET as empty(by accident) then recoveryimage will have no RAMDISK

How can I check if each of the dependencies is empty or not?
or is there any other suggestion?

```
1016 $(INSTALLED_RECOVERYIMAGE_TARGET): $(MKBOOTFS) $(MKBOOTIMG) $(MINIGZIP) \
1017         $(INSTALLED_RAMDISK_TARGET) \
1018         $(INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET) \
1019         $(INTERNAL_RECOVERYIMAGE_FILES) \
1020         $(recovery_initrc) $(recovery_sepolicy) $(recovery_kernel) \
1021         $(INSTALLED_2NDBOOTLOADER_TARGET) \
1022         $(recovery_build_prop) $(recovery_resource_deps) \
1023         $(recovery_fstab) \
1024         $(RECOVERY_INSTALL_OTA_KEYS)
1025         $(call build-recoveryimage-target, $@)
```

I tried below method but in vain because foreach will skip variable which is empty

```
1016 RECOVERYIMAGE_REQUIRED := $(MKBOOTFS) $(MKBOOTIMG) $(MINIGZIP) \
1017         $(INSTALLED_RAMDISK_TARGET) \
1018         $(INSTALLED_BOOTIMAGE_TARGET) \
1019         $(INTERNAL_RECOVERYIMAGE_FILES) \
1020         $(recovery_initrc) $(recovery_sepolicy) $(recovery_kernel) \
1021         $(INSTALLED_2NDBOOTLOADER_TARGET) \
1022         $(recovery_build_prop) $(recovery_resource_deps) \
1023         $(recovery_fstab) \
1024         $(RECOVERY_INSTALL_OTA_KEYS)
1025         $(call build-recoveryimage-target, $@)
1026 $(foreach item,$(HOSDIMAGE_REQUIRED), \
1027    $(eval _item := $(strip $(item))) \
1028    $(if $(_item),$(info $(_item) checked),$(error dependency is empty)) \                                                                                                                               
1029    )
1030 $(INSTALLED_RECOVERYIMAGE_TARGET): $(RECOVERYIMAGE_REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh how I wish for a `--error-undefined-variables` to match the existing `--warn-undefined-variables`. In the mean time you can just use something like:

```
depvarnames := \
  MKBOOTFS \
  MKBOOTIMG \
  MINIGZIP \
  ⋮

deps := $(foreach _,${depvarnames},$(or $_,$(error $$$_ is empty!)))

${INSTALLED_RECOVERYIMAGE_TARGET}: ${deps}
    recipe
    ⋮
```

Comment: foreach will skip items which is empty in $(depvarnames), so it cannot help. but --warn-undefined-variables is a very good hint for me!

Comment: @wenchiching How so? The `$foreach` above steps through the variable _names_, none of which are empty. Further, the `$error` asserts that each of those variables has a non-zero expansion.

Answer (score 0):

below is my solution, looks stupid but it really help me a lot

```
NULL :=
SPACE := $(NULL) $(NULL)
DQUOTE = " 

RECOVERYIMAGE_REQUIRED := \
               "$(MKBOOTFS)" \
               "$(MKBOOTIMG)" \
               "$(MINIGZIP)" \
               "$(PRODUCT_OUT)/ramdisk.img" \
               "$(PRODUCT_OUT)/boot.img" \
               "$(rec_initrc)" \
               "$(rec_kernel)" \
               "$(rec_build_prop)" \
               "$(rec_resource_deps)" \
               "$(rec_fstab)"

$(foreach item, $(RECOVERYIMAGE_REQUIRED), \
    $(eval _item := $(strip $(item))) \
    $(if $(filter "", $(_item)),$(error dependency is empty),) \
)

RECOVERYIMAGE_OPTIONAL := \
               "$(INSTALLED_2NDBOOTLOADER_TARGET)" \

$(foreach item, $(RECOVERYIMAGE_REQUIRED) $(RECOVERYIMAGE_OPTIONAL), \
    $(if $(strip $(subst $(DQUOTE),$(SPACE),$(item))), \
         $(eval RECOVERYIMAGE_FINAL_LIST += $(strip $(subst $(DQUOTE),$(SPACE),$(item)))), \
    ) \ 
)

$(INSTALLED_RECOVERYIMAGE_TARGET): $(RECOVERYIMAGE_FINAL_LIST)
```